# Read data from sqlitedatabase using date

Tags: android

Hi,
   I am inserting date in database as,

long curr_date = System.currentTimeMillis();

When I look at my database the date appears as 2014-03-18. If date is less than 2 days.I want to pull all my name data and store it in a string.
How can I achieve that?. The below method pulls all the data from the database but doesn't pulls it querying just the date. Thanks in advance.

```
public static final String KEY_DATE = "current_date";

String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_DATE};

String result =" ";

Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);



 int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
            int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);


for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){


                result = result + c.getString(iName) + ",";    

            }
            return result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [SQLite datetime functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.htm) and look at the section modifiers. It has what you need. Basically, you need to do something like:

```
currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US)
        .format(calendar.getInstance().getTime());

Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, 
        columns, 
        "date(" + KEY_DATE + ",\"+2 days\")=?", 
        new String[] { currentDate }, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null);
```

(Disclaimer: I haven't tested this, there might be the stray syntax error in it... It should definitely be enough to point you in the right direction though.)

Comment: I am using milliseconds to query long twodaysago = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 2L;
             
             Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_DATE +  " > " + twodaysago, null, null, null, null);                                                                         int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
             int iDepression = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DEPRESSION);
 But I am having difficulty in getting the data in a string.

Comment: Not sure I understand what the problem is. What do you mean by getting "the data in a string"? Turning the `long` timestamp into something like YYYY-MM-DD? Have a look at the link I gave you, the answer to that problem is in there as well (`strftime`). Does the code I posted not do what you're looking for?